# CSS Precedence. Div Element Color is not Changing

Tags: css, colors

Well, I've a Div like below in `index.html`

```
<div class="first">Hey This is it.</div>
```

`first` class definition.

```
   .first{
          width: 55px;
          height: 55px;
          color: green;
      }
```

I'm trying to inject a new Class named `second` from external file `style.css` (I can't edit this file) with it's definition like below.

```
    .second{
          color: blue;
      }
```

After injecting, I can see the element like below in `index.html`.

```
<div class="first second">Hey This is it.</div>
```

But Why div color is still with Green?? I want to get the div text color as Blue. How to acheive this?? Thanks.

Comment: and if we don't see the **order** of your CSS we cannot help you

Comment: The external stylesheet would need to come after the stylesheet that contains the .first class.

Comment: I would make sure that your external file `style.css` is being read after your main CSS. So if both files are linked to in your HTML document make sure the file with the `.second` class is below the one with `.first`. CSS works as a cascade, so you may be overriding the `color: blue`. If this is not the case please give more information of how you are linking to the style sheets. I hope this helps. :-)